# Why am I having problems calling this method from a different class?

Tags: java, static

I am an eighth grader with a tight deadline on a java project.  I have my GUI all ready to go, except I need to take the two values from the two text fields, and send them to a method in a different class when I press a button.  I am having trouble calling the method I need.  All important code is below.

Code that is attempting to call the method:

```
 private void GoButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String Ntextfield = NumberTextField.getText();
    n = Integer.parseInt(Ntextfield);

    String Rtextfield = RateTextField.getText();
    r = Integer.parseInt(Rtextfield);
    //call PermMath class
    PermMath doTheMath = new PermMath();
    doTheMath.permutations(int n, int r);
}
```

Method I am trying to call:

```
class PermMath {
  static long factorial(int num){
      //other code is here
  }
  static long permutations(int n, int r){
        //code I want to call is here
  }
}
```

Comment: I honestly didn't knew they taught Java to eighth graders :)

Comment: So far, you have not explained the problem or error you have encountered. Are you running into an exception? Will the code not compile? Is the result not what you expect? Etc. Help us help you.

Comment: @adarshr, I go to a charter school, so we get to learn what we want to learn, so we can apply it to what we want to do with our lives. Just saying..

Comment: @CodeAdmiral That's seriously awesome! I wish I was given that sort of education!

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I am doing this in Netbeans, so it is just giving me an error that states: ".class" expected, two ";" expected's, and an unexpected value error

Comment: @adarshr Yeah, I had to give up my social life though, oh well.  Java is worth it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you have two mistakes:

1. You are passing two temporary integers called `n` and `r` instead of passing the two integers you modified earlier in your `GoButtonActionPerformed` function.
2. The `permutations` function is static, so there is no need to actually create an instance of the `PermMath` class.

Changing the function call to this should do it:

```
PermMath.permutations(n, r);
```

Comment: Wait, do I still need the    PermMath doTheMath = new PermMath(); ?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral No, since that would be creating a new instance of the PermMath class. Since the functions inside PermMath are static, there is no need to create an instance, you can just call them as shown in my example code.

Comment: Otay, thank you, that answers my question. Given, that it wont let me accept it for two minutes so just wait a little bit.

Answer (score 5):

The hint for you is the `static` keyword. Learn what it means and how it works.

Also, you're using the variables `n` and `r` even before declaring them.

```
n = Integer.parseInt(Ntextfield);
```

should come after you've done something like `int n = 0;`.

And while invoking a method, you don't declare the parameters. The below is wrong.

```
doTheMath.permutations(int n, int r);
```

Instead you do something like

```
doTheMath.permutations(n, r);
```

Comment: Oh, they are declared in main(), which calls the GUI class.  Will the variables transfer?

Comment: +1 for spotting the `doTheMath.permutations(int n, int r);` call. I'm embarassed that I didn't see that ... :(

Answer (score 1):

Note that if `PermMath` is in another package than the class which defines `GoButtonActionPerformed(...)` it won't be visible due to the lack of a `public` access modifier on the methods and even the class.

Btw, in Java method names should start with a lower case latter. While your style is valid code adhering to the convention makes it easier for other Java developers to read your code.

Another thing: you don't use the return value of `permutations(...)`. That might not be intented.

Comment: What do you mean with the last little bit?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral with using the return value? Well, you call `doTheMath.permutations(int n, int r);` and don't use the return value. I guess you want to store it somewhere or print it to the command line etc.

Comment: You have a very good point, I had overlooked that.  So I would just set a long to those inputs after they get processed, right?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral You can do whatever you want with that return value. One way might be to set some instance variable, write the value to some field for displaying the result etc. It's totally up to you.

Comment: So, I just call the class/method/function/thing, and set it to a long, right?  Then how would I do that?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral how would you do what, setting the value to a long variable? What about `long result = PermMath.permutations(int n, int r);` and go on from there?

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `static` methods in your `PermMath` class - these do not require an instantiation of the class to be called. You simply call them with:

```
PermMath.permutations(n,r);
```

Check out the track for this at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html